# Is it better to move this anonymous function to a real named function?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code:

```
   $('#dataTable .select-topic')
        .click(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('data-list') == "N") {
                $(this).attr('data-list', 'Y')
                var topicSelectHtml = $('#TopicID')
                .clone()
                .find("optgroup:first").remove().end()
                .find("option[value$='**']").remove().end().html();
                $(this).html(topicSelectHtml);
                $(this).attr('data-clicked', 'Y')
            }
        })
        .change(function () {
            $(this).attr("title", $("option:selected", this).text());
            var type = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
            updateField(entity, $(this), type);
        })
```

It's applied to a few hundred rows as each row has a select. For efficiency would it be better for me to create named functions and attach these to the click and change. If so then how could I do this for the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the function is named or not won't really affect performance. Rather than creating and binding hundreds of different instances of the functions, however, it might be better to just create a delegated event handler once and bind that to the parent:

```
$('#dataTable').on('click', '.select-topic', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-list') == "N") {
        $(this).attr('data-list', 'Y')
        var topicSelectHtml = $('#TopicID').clone().find("optgroup:first").remove().end().find("option[value$='**']").remove().end().html();
        $(this).html(topicSelectHtml);
        $(this).attr('data-clicked', 'Y')
    }
}).on('change', '.select-topic', function() {
    $(this).attr("title", $("option:selected", this).text());
    var type = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    updateField(entity, $(this), type);
});​
```

This will handle clicks on the same elements, but with only a single function being bound, which will help performance.

Comment: Your idea sounds good. If I were to dynamically refresh the contents of the #datatable HTML then would I need to run this javascript again after the refresh?

Comment: Depends what you mean by 'refresh the contents'; this method would work for all `.select-topic` elements in `#dataTable`, present or future, without having to be rerun. If you add rows, for example, the click will work fine as is. Otherwise, if you do some kind of server post-back (not ajax), this will have to be run again (though I assume it would run automatically on page-load anyway, so that would be fine). Does that help?

Comment: Thanks very much. I will implement your suggestion. It looks very good.

Answer (score 0):

Change anonymous function to a named function won't improve the performance anyway. Just use the clean style you think.

Comment: Is it not the case that it attaches all that code to every select? I was thinking there would be a few hundred instances of the same code attached to every select event with the way it is coded above.

Comment: @Gemma No, the function will interpreted only once when you bind it.